# Unable to add list member

Tags: python, yaml, ruamel.yaml

I'm trying to add a new list member but I'm not being successful.

This is what I have:

```py
import sys
from ruamel.yaml import YAML
from ruamel.yaml.comments import CommentedMap as cm
from ruamel.yaml.comments import CommentedSeq as cs

yaml_doc = """\
Condition:
  Like:
    - !Join ['',['abc:def:', !Ref 'XYZ::Rert', ':', '123', ':tty:*']]
"""
yaml = YAML()
yaml.preserve_quotes = True
yaml.width = 4096
data = yaml.load(yaml_doc)
ref = data['Condition']['Like']

new_member = "!Join ['',['abc:def:', !Ref 'XYZ::Rert', ':', '456', ':tty:*']]"
# new_member2 = '!Join ['',['abc:def:', !Ref 'XYZ::Rert', ':', '456', ':tty:*']]'

ref.append(new_member)
# ref.append(new_member2)

yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

The output is

```
Condition:
  Like:
  - !Join ['', ['abc:def:', !Ref 'XYZ::Rert', ':', '123', ':tty:*']]
  - "!Join ['',['abc:def:', !Ref 'XYZ::Rert', ':', '456', ':tty:*']]"
```

I do not want the double quotes.

If I uncomment the section related to the new_member2 I get and error

```py
  File "ec2-recover-2.py", line 18
    new_member2 = '!Join ['',['abc: def: ', !Ref 'XYZ: : Rert', ': ', '456', ': tty: *']]'
                                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

How can I add a member list in this format `!Join ['', ['abc:def:', !Ref 'XYZ::Rert', ':', '123', ':tty:*']]` and it not having single or double quotes in the final YAML?

Comment: `yaml.preserve_quotes = True` is probably causing this. Try setting that to `False`

Comment: @rdas That is not causing it, and it should be set to `True`, otherwise the spurious single quotes in around `:tty:*` will be stripped from the output.

Comment: I need the `yaml.preserve_quotes = True`flag because i need it for other parts of the file that I did not show on my example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be thinking that this:

```
!Join ['',['abc:def:', !Ref 'XYZ::Rert', ':', '123', ':tty:*']]
```

is a plain scalar that gets loaded as a string in Python. It is not. A
plain scalar cannot start with an exclamation mark, as YAML uses that
to introduces a [tag](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2761292),
and what you load from there is quite a complicated object:

```
import ruamel.yaml

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
data = yaml.load("!Join ['',['abc:def:', !Ref 'XYZ::Rert', ':', '123', ':tty:*']]")
print(data)
```

prints:

```
['', ['abc:def:', <ruamel.yaml.comments.TaggedScalar object at 0x7f405265fa58>, ':', '123', ':tty:*']]
```

You can build such objects from scratch, but it is probably more easy, to load
the list item you want to add, from its YAML string representation. If you want to engage in some DIY, you
can construct it the entry from `CommentedSeq` and `TaggedScalar` instances as well:

```
import sys
from ruamel.yaml import YAML
from ruamel.yaml.comments import CommentedSeq as cs
from ruamel.yaml.comments import TaggedScalar as ts
from ruamel.yaml.scalarstring import SingleQuotedScalarString as sq

yaml_doc = """\
Condition:
  Like:
    - !Join ['',['abc:def:', !Ref 'XYZ::Rert', ':', '123', ':tty:*']]
"""
yaml = YAML()
yaml.preserve_quotes = True
yaml.width = 4096
data = yaml.load(yaml_doc)
ref = data['Condition']['Like']

new_member = yaml.load("!Join ['',['abc:def:', !Ref 'XYZ::Rert', ':', '456', ':tty:*']]")

ts1 = ts()
ts1.value = 'XYZ::Rert'
ts1.style = "'"
ts1.yaml_set_tag('!Ref')

new_member2 = cs([sq(''), [sq('abc:def:'), ts1 , sq(':'), sq('789'), sq(':tty:*')]])
new_member2.yaml_set_tag('!Join')
new_member2.fa.set_flow_style()

ref.append(new_member)
ref.append(new_member2)

yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

which gives:

```
Condition:
  Like:
  - !Join ['', ['abc:def:', !Ref 'XYZ::Rert', ':', '123', ':tty:*']]
  - !Join ['', ['abc:def:', !Ref 'XYZ::Rert', ':', '456', ':tty:*']]
  - !Join ['', ['abc:def:', !Ref 'XYZ::Rert', ':', '789', ':tty:*']]
```

(If you really want to figure out how to construct something like `new_member2` yourself, it helps
to load the output you want from YAML and print the individual items, their types and
their attributes)

Comment: It works perfectly. Thanks for all the help provided @Anthon